# fullpage.js active class show two half sections

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Hey i'm using the fullpage.js plugin and want my page to start at the last slide. The last slide have the class active, wich is suppose to load the side to a specific slide. The result is that the page shows have of the active slide and half of the slide above.

Is there anyone who knows what the problem is?

http://itu.dk/people/cnos/diam/Eksamensprojekt%20kopi/journey.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing fullPage.js twice [here](http://itu.dk/people/cnos/diam/Eksamensprojekt%20kopi/js/script.js)...

And you should be including the CSS styles before the javascript ones.

You should only have one initialization:

```
//FULL PAGE CODE
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    css3: true,
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    easing: "easeOutQuad",
    scrollOverflow: true,
    onLeave: slideLeave,
    paddingTop: '0px',
    verticalCentered: false,

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        $( "#ufoscroll" ).hide( 0 );
        $( "#ufopic" ).show( 0 );

        if(index == 9){
        $( "#makurtale" ).show( "" );
        }

        if(index == 10)
        $( ".solbillede" ).show( "" );
        $( "#ufoscroll" ).hide( 0 );
        $( "#ufopic" ).show( 0 );

    },

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var leavingSection = $(this);
        if(direction =='up'){
            $( "#ufoscroll" ).show( 0 );
            $( "#ufopic" ).hide( 0 );              
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: it fixed all my problems, including some which isn't mentioned. thx!